# Search Cursor in ArcPy for a range

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class

I'm getting an error while using the where_clause for a length which has a "float" datatype.
While other variables in a function are working fine, even on ArcMap "length" part is working.
Error be like : "Where clause is not a string". I am not mentioning about import arcpy, workspace & all.

Currently, I'm using ArcMap 10.7

Here's my code:

```
def Calculate_Pipe_Risk_Score(Material, OPERATINGPRESSURE, MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT,MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT, INSTALLATIONDATELOWERLIMIT, INSTALLATIONDATEUPPERLIMIT):

    ML_Out_fields = ["MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT" ,"MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT" , "OVERALLRISKSCORE"]
    ML_where_Clause = (MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT <= MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT and MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT >= MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT)
    Table_Pipe_Cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table_Pipe, ML_Out_fields, ML_where_Clause)
    for row in Table_Pipe_Cursor:
        ML_Risk_Score = row[2]
        print (ML_Risk_Score)

Calculate_Pipe_Risk_Score("Material" , "OPERATINGPRESSURE" , "MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT" ,"MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT" ,  "INSTALLATIONDATELOWERLIMIT", "INSTALLATIONDATEUPPERLIMIT")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *where* clause should be a string. As it is now, it is a statement and will be interpreted by Python itself (it will evaluate to the boolean value `true` or `false`, hence the error *Where clause is not a string*).

This should probably work:

```
ML_where_Clause = "(MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT <= {} and MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT >= {})".format(MEASUREDLENGTHUPPERLIMIT, MEASUREDLENGTHLOWERLIMIT)
```